# why initializing a std::string to "" (through lambda) crashes?

Tags: c++, lambda, initialization, c++20, selfinitialization

Why initializing a `std::string` to `""` (through lambda) crashes?

This will not crash:

```
static std::string strTest2 = 
   [](){std::string * s = &strTest2; (*s) = "a"; return s->c_str();}();`
```

This trick (initialize it to non empty first, but the intended final value is empty) will not crash:

```
static std::string strTest3 =
   [](){std::string * s = &strTest3; (*s) = "b"; (*s) = ""; return s->c_str();}();
```

CRASHES here at `(*s) = ""`. Is it because it is an empty string? Is it special? Is the `std::string` not constructed/initialized when assigning to `""`?

```
static std::string strTest1 =
   [](){std::string * s = &strTest1; (*s) = ""; return s->c_str();}();`
```

Comment: Now I understand that undefined behaviour is using a not initialized variable. But just capturing it's address has nothing to do with calling internal functions of the variable's class, nor accessing anything inside it or anything else that could write to such var at that moment. Just capturing the variable's address and let it complete initialization doesnt look like UB I guess. REASON: I want to do it that way because I can create static global config vars that are intended to be used just in a restricted scope of a single function, and initialized lazily on demand!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these are undefined behavior. The fact that some of them don't cause a crash is irrelevant; they're all nonsensical code. Some of them happen to "work" for you. This time.

All of them are UB for the same reason: you're accessing an object before it gets initialized. `strTest` cannot legally be accessed in the expression used to initialize it. Which is precisely what your lambda attempts to do.

Why that particular one crashes on your compiler and build settings and the others don't doesn't matter. None of them represent valid C++ code.

Comment: so this would be correct right? `static std::string strTest1 = [](){ strPointer = &strTest1; return ""; }();` as I want to init strPointer to &strTest1 and also set a default value to strTest1, but now, I am not touching strTest1 before it is initialized.

Comment: @AquariusPower: "*I want to init strPointer to &strTest1 and also set a default value to strTest1*" Those are two separate operations; why do you insist on doing them in one step? Furthermore, why do you need a pointer to a static variable? All of these sound like XY problems.

Comment: because all these static vars will go to a vector and will be allowed to be modified by the user in real time. When they are modified, the change will be detected and proper validations applied to grant the input was correct. All in a the same step is to make the coding "simple/compact". My concern is: it is working as the static var address is being properly captured, but I am not sure if that could become undefined behavior someday..

Comment: @AquariusPower: Then this seems like an XY problem. They shouldn't be "static vars" at all; they should just be objects in a vector that can be modified and have those modifications tracked. Nothing about your goal requires doing it *this* way. And they won't "become undefined behavior someday" because they are all already UB *today*.

Comment: As I understood, undefined behaviour is using a not initialized variable. But just capturing it's address has nothing to do with calling internal functions of the variable's class, nor accessing anything inside it or anything else that could write to such var at that moment. Just capturing the variable's address and let it complete initialization doesnt look like UB. I want to do it that way because I can create static global config vars that are intended to be used just in a restricted scope of a single function, and initialized lazily on demand!

Comment: I insisted a lot :>, but got a condition that had no fix (the first var being created my wrong way always failed). I finally changed the code to create a new object in a map and just return it to the static pointer variable and configured details thru lambda where needed. thx!